# python-flask html form help/suggestions

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, http-status-code-400

I'm rendering a page for users to browse ad listings on a practice site. On the 'browse' page, I have three separate forms, two are select fields and the other is a textfield. The select fields allow a user to change location or transaction type, and the text field allows them to change the thing they are searching for. I wanted to do this pure HTML and not use flask-wtf. I have successfully got the part where they can change location working, but as soon as I add code for the other options, it breaks and I get a **400 bad request error**. Any suggestions or guidance as to why this is isn't working when I add in the forms for changing item and transaction type?

```
 @app.route('/find-it/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def browse():
   try:

    location = session.get('location', None)
    transType = session.get('transType', None)
    item = session.get('item', None)        

    data = browseQuery()

     if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['changeLocation'] != '':
            print('location changed')
            location = request.form['changeLocation']
            session['location'] = location
            return redirect(url_for('browse', location=location))
        elif request.form['changeType'] != '':
            print('type changed')
            transType = request.form['changetype']
            session['transType'] = transType
            return redirect('browse', transType=transType)
        else:
            if request.form['changeItem'] != '':
                print('item changed')
                item = request.form['changeItem']
                session['item'] = item
                return redirect(url_for('browse', item=item))

      return render_template('all-classifieds.html',location=location,transType=transType, data=data)
except Exception as e:
    return (str(e))
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="changeLocation" name="changeLocation" action="">

                    <select name="changeLocation" id="changeLocation" style="margin-right: 5%; float: left;">
                        <optgroup label="Where?">
                            <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;"></option>
                            <option>option 1</option>
                            <option>option 2</option>

                        </optgroup></select></form>


<button type="submit" id="submit" form="changeLocation" style="padding: 0 3px; float:left;"
                        class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>




 <form method="post" name="changeType" id="changeType">


                    <select name="changeType" id="changeType" style="margin-right: 5%; float: left;">
                        <optgroup label="...">
                            <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;"></option>
                            <option>option 1</option>
                            <option>option 2</option>
                            <option>option 3</option>

                        </optgroup>
                    </select>



<form method="post" name="changeType" id="changeType">


                    <select name="changeType" id="changeType" style="margin-right: 5%; float: left;">
                        <optgroup label="Look for things that are...">
                            <option selected style="display:none;color:#eee;"></option>
                            <option>asdf</option>
                            <option>asdfasdf</option>
                            <option>asdfasdfasdf</option>

                        </optgroup>
                    </select></form>

<button type="submit" id="submit" form="changeType" style="padding: 0 3px; float:left;"
                        class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>


<form method="post" name="changeItem" id="changeItem">
                    <input type="text" name="changeItem" value="" id="changeItem" placeholder=""/>
                </form>

<button type="submit" id="submit" form="changeItem" style="padding: 0 3px; float:left;"
                        class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use debug=True, then you'll see what the actual error is?

Comment: so new to this. I do have debug=True. not sure how to use it I guess? @DanielRoseman I dont get a traceback page. it just says 400 bad request on the page when i submit and that is all

Comment: Do you have code to handle loading the page when you receive a `GET` request?  I see the code here for `POST`, is there more you aren't showing?

Comment: I just added a couple more lines i left out but it shouldn't make a difference. What's above is all i have @coralv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem you asked about:**

With

```
if request.form['changeLocation'] != '':
```

you are probably trying to find out if that specific form was used. The problem is: when the correct form was used this check works but if a different form was used the `request.form` dictionary throws a key error. But it is not a normal `KeyError`. Flask will translate that "special" error to a `400 Bad Request`.

To check if a certain key is present in the form data use the `in` operator

```
if "changeLocation" in request.form:
    # you can use request.form["changeLocation"] here
elif "changeType" in request.form:
    # here request.form["changeType"] is present
...
```

**Another problem:**

This line

```
render_template('all-classifieds.html',location=location,transType=transType, data=data)
```

won't work, because `location` and `transType` are defined in the `if` blocks. It will fail if the blocks are not executed.

**Something different:**

```
else:
    if condition:
         do_something
```

can be rewritten as

```
elif condition:
    do_something
```

Comment: Thank you, @Wombatz